# Adding a "Home" hyperlink to a shape using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

this question has been asked before but the solution I found does not seem to work, no matter what I try - Here's my problem:

I have several worksheets in a workbook. I created a macro that creates a button (using a shape) and places a hyperlink on it to the first sheet in the book called "Crawl Summary". The macro then places that button on every other worksheet within the book.

The macro that is recorded is this:

```
'Creates a navigation button back to Crawl Summary Page on each page

    Sheets("Robots.txt Blocked").Select
    Range("A1").Select
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 0, 1.2, 52.2, 13.2). _
        Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "SUMMARY"
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 7). _
        ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 7).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.9540229885, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.9090909091, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = _
        msoAlignCenter
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 1")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), Address:=""
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Noindexed Pages").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

As you can see, the code ends with the button being copied to the next worksheet called "Noindexed Pages" but the hyperlink for both pages above is not applied.

This is apparently because of the explanation on this Stackoverflow answer:

[Excel VBA add hyperlink to shape to link to another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225024/excel-vba-add-hyperlink-to-shape-to-link-to-another-sheet)

The recommended solution given on this page is as follows:

```
Sub SetHyperlinkOnShape()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")

    Dim hyperLinkedShape As Shape

    Set hyperLinkedShape = ws.Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 1")

    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=hyperLinkedShape, Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="Sheet4!C4:C8", ScreenTip:="yadda yadda"
End Sub
```

But this just doesn't work for me no matter what I try, even if I create

Can anyone advise on what code I need to successfully add an internal hyperlink to "Crawl Summary" on the button (shape) in the active worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

**I.** Make sure that you have a shape called "Rounded Rectangle 1" in a sheet named "Sheet 6".

[image]

**II.** Make sure you have Sheet1.

Pretty much this code works (taken from yours):

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetHyperlinkOnShape()


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")

    Dim hyperLinkedShape As Shape

    Set hyperLinkedShape = ws.Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 1")

    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=hyperLinkedShape, Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="Sheet1!C4:C8", ScreenTip:="yadda yadda"
End Sub
```

Here is a quick way to create a shape from the macro recorder with a specified name:

```
Sub Makro1()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 104.4000787402, 42.75, _
        3.5999212598, 5.25).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "JoeBanana3"
End Sub
```

Comment: As it is on 2 different workbooks, you'll need to specify full name in `Address` property ;)

Comment: Hey thanks, that opens another question I have - How do you know the name of the shape? Traditionally I record a macro that selects shape in question then look at the code generated to see what its been defined as but from your screenshot, it looks like you've got it displaying in the bar without having to do that?

Comment: There are two options - either take a look at the bar and change the name there or set a name when you create it! @Superhans

Comment: Hi Sorry, you are assuming I am experienced in VBA, I'm not sadly. When I click on the table, I see nothing in the bar and I don't know how to set a name when I create the table either. Help.

Comment: @Superhans - click on the form and it would appear. And see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `SubAddress` property for the Sheet and Range, 
and the `Address` property with the FullName (path + name) of the file,
and as `Anchor` use the object that you created/pasted (`Set sH = ...`)

```
wS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sH, _
                    Address:="C:\TestFolder\TestFile.xlsm", _
                    SubAddress:="'Sheets name'!A1", _
                    ScreenTip:="Go to home"
```

Creates a navigation button to Crawl Summary Page (properly indented and cleaned of `Select`s) :

```
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim sH As Shape

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Robots.txt Blocked")

Set sH = wS.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 0, 1.2, 52.2, 13.2)

With sH
    With .ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange
        .Characters.Text = "SUMMARY"
        With .Characters(1, 7)
            With .ParagraphFormat
                .FirstLineIndent = 0
                .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
            End With '.ParagraphFormat
            With .Font
                .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
                .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
                With .Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
                    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With '.Fill
                .Size = 11
                .Name = "+mn-lt"
            End With '.Font
        End With '.Characters(1, 7)
    End With '
    With .ShapeRange
        .ScaleWidth 1.9540229885, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleHeight 0.9090909091, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        With .TextFrame2
            .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
            .TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        End With '.TextFrame2
    End With '.ShapeRange
End With 'sH

wS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sH, _
                    Address:="C:\TestFolder\TestFile.xlsm", _
                    SubAddress:="'Crawl Summary'!A1", _
                    ScreenTip:="Go to home"
sH.Copy
Set sH = Sheets("Noindexed Pages").Range("A1").Paste
'... Check if hyperlink is still ok or reuse above code
```